# Function composition in rust

Tags: rust

In rust fp-core crate there is a compose function, but it is very limited for my liking.
So I made a macro which uses the function composition syntax of Haskell.
I would like to know why fp-core didn't do something like this in the first place?

What advice would you give me since this is the first macro I ever wrote in rust.

Here is my code:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! compose {

    // end
    (@inner . $g:ident $e:expr) =>
    {
        $g($e)
    };

    (@inner . ( $g:ident $($param:expr),+ )  $e:expr) =>
    {
        $g ( $( $param ),+ , $e )
    };

    // middle
    (@inner . ( $f:ident $($param:expr),+ )  $( $gs:tt )* ) =>
    {
        $f( $( $param ),+ , compose!{ @inner $( $gs )* } )
    };

    (@inner . $f:ident $( $gs:tt )* ) =>
    {
        $f( compose!{ @inner $( $gs )* } )
    };

    //start
    ( $f:ident $( $tokens:tt )* ) =>
    {
        $f(compose!{ @inner $( $tokens )* } )
    };

    ( ( $f:ident  $( $param:expr ),+ ) $( $tokens:tt )* ) =>
    {
         $f( $( $param ),+ , compose!{ @inner $( $tokens )* } )
    };

}

#[cfg(test)]
mod compose_tests {

    fn add_3(x:u32) -> u32 {
        x + 3
    }

    fn double(x:u32) -> u32 {
        x * 2
    }

    fn my_add(x :u32, y :u32) -> u32
    {
        x + y
    }

    #[test]
    fn simple_test() {
        assert_eq!(compose!{double . add_3 2}, 10);
    }

    #[test]
    fn double_a_lot() {
        assert_eq!(compose!{double . double . double . double . double . double . double 1}, 128);
    }

    #[test]
    fn simple_partial_app() {
        let mut x = compose!{double . (my_add 2) 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 6);
        x = compose!{(my_add 2) . double 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 4);
        x = compose!{double . (my_add 2) . double 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 8);
        x = compose!{(my_add 2) . double . double 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 6);
        x = compose!{double . double . (my_add 1) 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 8);
        x = compose!{(my_add 2) . (my_add 2) . double 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 6);
        x = compose!{(my_add 2) . (my_add 2) . (my_add 1) 1};
        assert_eq!(x, 6);
    }
}
```